# Freelance job offer on public job board to buy Stack Overflow reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, accounts

I've found a job offer on a public job board [here](https://www.freelancer.com.bd/projects/Javascript-Java/Build-Reputation-StackOverflow.html#header-login-modal) which has following description:

> Looking for a developer to user my account to answer questions on
>   StackOverflow in order to build up my reputation. Questions must be
>   related to listed skills(java, c# etc) Paying 20$ per 100 reputation
>   points before 1000 reputation points. and 30$ per 100 reputation
>   points after 1000 reputation points. I pay frequently, per 1000 points
>   collected (200$ or 300$ at a time). Thanks.
>   [image: Build Up Reputation on StackOverflow]

- Is this legal for both parties (employer and the employee)?
- Is Stack Overflow concerned about these kinds of things?
- What are the possible side effects for this kind of thing to real contributors?

Comment: Such kind of stuff looks like needing ***destruction*** of whatever accounts they're actually running on SO (client or supplier), or were bought to be supported.

Comment: Thats messed up; and gives us all a bad name.

Comment: If they neglect to cite any time restraints they'll need a well paid job to meet your payments as your awesome answers just keep on giving: year after year.

Comment: Wow, one good answer and I'm in for forty bucks. I'm sold!